# What is the definition of integration $\int{\rm d} z{\rm d} \bar z$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to know how to calculate the integration(it is from a physics book):
$$
\int {\rm d}z{\rm d}\bar z \exp (-z\bar z) = \pi
$$
But I even do not know the definition of ${\rm d}z{\rm d}\bar z$. Maybe if you treat it as a 2-form, then,
$$
{\rm d}z\wedge{\rm d}\bar z = -2i {\rm d}x\wedge{\rm d}y
$$
But the result $\pi$ implies it treat the term as,
$$
{\rm d}z{\rm d}\bar z \to {\rm d}x{\rm d}y
$$
I have read this question [complex integral over $dz\,dz^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607497/complex-integral-over-dz-dz), I get really confused. Can someone give me the definition in math or some references for this.

Really  thanks.

Comment: Why not assume they forgot the $-2i$ constant, does it bring any trouble somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with $z=x+iy$, compute the (absolute value of the) Jacobian to get a Gaussian integral of the type
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \, e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\, .
$$
This kind of notation is common in mathematical physics, especially in the study of coherent states, where it is often rewritten as $d^2\alpha$, with $\alpha=x+ip$, as [in this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Mathematical_features_of_the_canonical_coherent_states).  The notation using $z$ rather than $\alpha$ is favoured in the early papers of Perelomov and the Russian school.

Comment: the Jacobian is $-2\rm i$, so the absolute $|\cdot|$ gives $2$. I think maybe it is just a definition of the notation.